# Given $a+b=cd$ and $c+d=ab$, prove that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\ge 0$ for $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality

As in the title. I'm not used to dealing with such inequalities, so any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best you can do is $$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)≥0$$

To see this, note that $$(c+1)(d+1)=cd+c+d+1=a+b+c+d+1$$

Similarly, $$(a+1)(b+1)=a+b+c+d+1$$

thus your product is $(a+b+c+d+1)^2$ which is non-negative (but which might be $0$).  The example $$\{a,b,c,d\}=\{-1,1,-1,0\}$$ shows that the product can in fact be $0$.

Note:  I see the question has been modified to read $"≥0"$, which is indeed true.

Answer (score 4):

First expand in two parts the products and use the given equations to simplify, like this:
$$(ab+a+b+1)(cd+c+d+1)\ge0$$
$$(ab+cd+1)(ab+cd+1)\ge0$$
$$(ab+cd+1)^2\ge0.$$